# Vue loads and renders well, but then stops working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have an application using Vue and Webpack. I have this configuration from the webpack docs:

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js')
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Production',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    }
})
```

In the front I have some Vue code that ran when I developed it using webpack-dev-server.

When I run it with that configuration the page loads with the parameters interpolated and the directives rendered (i.e. v-for) and all stops working (except for a setInterval), the ui is not updated, the events does not trigger the handlers, nothing.

index.html

```
<div id="app" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Title</h1>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Lorem ipsum faciebat <i><b>'{{randomWord}}'</b></i>?
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {mockedData} from './mocked-data';
import './components/search-bar';
import './components/word-cta';

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function(){
        const words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "faz", "boo", "foz", "bor"]
        let i = 0
        const getRandomWord = function(){
            if(i == words.length - 1){
                i = 0
            } else {
                i += 1
            }

            return words[i]
        }

        const data = {
            randomWord: words[0],
            lastWords: mockedData,
            result: ""
        }

        setInterval(function(){
            data.randomWord = getRandomWord()
        }, 1700)

        return data
    },
    methods: {
        onSearch: function(result){
            this.result = result;
        }
    }
})
```

I have no idea of what is happening... The console does not help. Below is the output:

> vue.esm.js:8439 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better
>   development experience: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
>   vue.esm.js:8449 You are running Vue in development mode. Make sure to
>   turn on production mode when deploying for production. See more tips
>   at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the problem is to import Vue using webpack. If I remove the `import Vue from 'vue';`
lines that I have on my .js files and put

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

on my index.html, the problem is fixed and JS behaves as expected.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Ensure that you're using the development version of Vue.js as well to ensure that tracking errors will be easier. You can switch back to the production version afterward.

Comment: I just added the output of the console. Nothing relevant I think

Comment: Taking a closer look, I would recommend removing some of that logic from your `data` attribute. Specifically, something like the `setInterval` call should probably be executed in the `mounted` lifecycle hook. As a general rule of thumb, you should treat `data` is being statically declared, while you should use `mounted` for any runtime declarations of data. Whether or not this will resolve your issue, I can't say, but it will still go a long ways toward improving your code quality.

Comment: Reading the docs, I don't think I can ensure the run of a function in intervals of 1700 miliseconds using the mounted hook. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Store the return value of `setInterval` in a data field. The interval will then be possible to reference later on as needed. Additionally, do something like `var this_vue_instance = this;` prior to entering the `setInterval` call so that you may update your `randomWord` value via `this_vue_instance.randomWord = . . .;` or through a method call via `this_vue_instance.setRandomWord();`.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that u missed babel-loader in your webpack config file, so "import" syntax cant be recognized by webpack, and also u should change  'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' to 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'.